# c# redirect to new tab and redirect current page

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to pres on button in aspx page and then in the code behind (cs), redirect the current page to different link and open new tab with new link.

i tried to do:

```
  Response.Write("window.open('"+newPath+"','_blank')");
  Response.Redirect("~/book_details.aspx);
```

but every time i redirect only to ~/book_details.aspx (the second redirect) and the new tap with newPath does not open.

anybody have an idea how to implement it correctly?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better never to use `Response.Write` and `Response.Redirect` together. `Response.Redirect` works best when no other output was written, and *if* it works (this may be browser dependent) then the output from `Response.Write` may have little or no effect because the browser loads the new page immediately after.

Best is to do both actions in javascript. And you also need a `<script>` tag for that.

Like this:

```
var redirectUrl = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/book_details.aspx");

var js = "window.open('" + newPath + "','_blank');"
       + "location.replace('" + redirectUrl + "');";

Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>" + js + "</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Greetings it should be like below, when you are calling `javascript` method within `Response.Write` you need to add `<script></script>`, also call your address within the `Response.Write`

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('~/book_details.aspx','_blank'</script>");
```